# Error During Compiling Arduino Code (NodeMCU)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, arduino, arduino-esp8266

I have been working with NodeMCU for 1 week but suddenly yesterday, while compiling NodeMCU again, as usual, it is showing error during compiling and not uploading the code. Please help me get out of it.

This is the error coming

```
Arduino: 1.8.12 (Windows 8.1), Board: "NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module), 80 MHz, Flash, Legacy (new can return nullptr), All SSL ciphers (most compatible), 4MB (FS:2MB OTA:~1019KB), 2, v2 Lower Memory, Disabled, None, Only Sketch, 115200"

In file included from C:\Users\Govind\Documents\Arduino\libraries\arduino_238892\src/BlynkApiArduino.h:14:0,

                 from C:\Users\Govind\Documents\Arduino\libraries\arduino_238892\src/BlynkSimpleEsp8266.h:24,

                 from C:\Users\Govind\Desktop\Stepper_Motor_Joystick_2.21\Stepper_Motor_Joystick_2.21.ino:3:

C:\Users\Govind\Documents\Arduino\libraries\arduino_238892\src/Blynk/BlynkApi.h: In instantiation of 'void BlynkApi<Proto>::syncVirtual(Args ...) [with Args = {}; Proto = BlynkProtocol<BlynkArduinoClientGen<Client> >]':

C:\Users\Govind\Desktop\Stepper_Motor_Joystick_2.21\Stepper_Motor_Joystick_2.21.ino:69:25:   required from here

C:\Users\Govind\Documents\Arduino\libraries\arduino_238892\src/Blynk/BlynkApi.h:143:9: error: no matching function for call to 'BlynkParam::add_multi()'

         cmd.add_multi(pins...);

         ^

C:\Users\Govind\Documents\Arduino\libraries\arduino_238892\src/Blynk/BlynkApi.h:143:9: note: candidates are:

In file included from C:\Users\Govind\Documents\Arduino\libraries\arduino_238892\src/Blynk/BlynkApi.h:16:0,

                 from C:\Users\Govind\Documents\Arduino\libraries\arduino_238892\src/BlynkApiArduino.h:14,

                 from C:\Users\Govind\Documents\Arduino\libraries\arduino_238892\src/BlynkSimpleEsp8266.h:24,

                 from C:\Users\Govind\Desktop\Stepper_Motor_Joystick_2.21\Stepper_Motor_Joystick_2.21.ino:3:

C:\Users\Govind\Documents\Arduino\libraries\arduino_238892\src/Blynk/BlynkParam.h:111:10: note: template<class T, class ... Args> void BlynkParam::add_multi(T)

     void add_multi(T last) {

          ^

C:\Users\Govind\Documents\Arduino\libraries\arduino_238892\src/Blynk/BlynkParam.h:111:10: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:

In file included from C:\Users\Govind\Documents\Arduino\libraries\arduino_238892\src/BlynkApiArduino.h:14:0,

                 from C:\Users\Govind\Documents\Arduino\libraries\arduino_238892\src/BlynkSimpleEsp8266.h:24,

                 from C:\Users\Govind\Desktop\Stepper_Motor_Joystick_2.21\Stepper_Motor_Joystick_2.21.ino:3:

C:\Users\Govind\Documents\Arduino\libraries\arduino_238892\src/Blynk/BlynkApi.h:143:9: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided

         cmd.add_multi(pins...);

         ^

In file included from C:\Users\Govind\Documents\Arduino\libraries\arduino_238892\src/Blynk/BlynkApi.h:16:0,

                 from C:\Users\Govind\Documents\Arduino\libraries\arduino_238892\src/BlynkApiArduino.h:14,

                 from C:\Users\Govind\Documents\Arduino\libraries\arduino_238892\src/BlynkSimpleEsp8266.h:24,

                 from C:\Users\Govind\Desktop\Stepper_Motor_Joystick_2.21\Stepper_Motor_Joystick_2.21.ino:3:

C:\Users\Govind\Documents\Arduino\libraries\arduino_238892\src/Blynk/BlynkParam.h:116:10: note: template<class T, class ... Args> void BlynkParam::add_multi(T, Args ...)

     void add_multi(T head, Args... tail) {

          ^

C:\Users\Govind\Documents\Arduino\libraries\arduino_238892\src/Blynk/BlynkParam.h:116:10: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:

In file included from C:\Users\Govind\Documents\Arduino\libraries\arduino_238892\src/BlynkApiArduino.h:14:0,

                 from C:\Users\Govind\Documents\Arduino\libraries\arduino_238892\src/BlynkSimpleEsp8266.h:24,

                 from C:\Users\Govind\Desktop\Stepper_Motor_Joystick_2.21\Stepper_Motor_Joystick_2.21.ino:3:

C:\Users\Govind\Documents\Arduino\libraries\arduino_238892\src/Blynk/BlynkApi.h:143:9: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided

         cmd.add_multi(pins...);

         ^

exit status 1
Error compiling for board NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module).

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

I am currently trying to run stepper motors using the **AccelStepper** library and **Blynk** Library and also included **Esp8266** Library for connectivity. I am not able to understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you called Blynk.syncVirtual() without any arguments. You need to include at least one virtual pin, like this:

```
  Blynk.syncVirtual(V4);
```